# Angular 2 nested ngFor not iterating

Tags: angular

I have this html:

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let category of categories">
  <h3>{{category.name}} ({{category.links.length}})</h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let link of category.links">
        <a href="" [href]="link.url" target="_blank">{{link.displayName}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I loop through a list of categories and for each category I loop through a list of links.

The problem is the nested `ngFor`: it doesn't iterate anything. I am certain that there are items in that list because `({{category.links.length}})` gives ma a result.

Also, when I dump my category list to the console, I can see the complete object graph: every category has at lest one item in the `links` array.

So, what am I missing here? What do I need to do to get this working?

Edit:
This is the generated html (an li tag)

```
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}-->
```

here is the corresponsing typescript:

```
constructor(private linkService: LinkService){
  this.linkService.getLinks().subscribe(p => {console.log(p); this.categories = p});
}
```

And here are the definitions of Category and LinkItem:

```
export class Category {
    name : string;
    links = new Array<LinkItem>();

    constructor(name:string)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    addLink(linkItem : LinkItem)
    {
        this.links.push(linkItem);
    }
}

export class LinkItem {
    url:string;
    displayName:string;

    constructor(url:string, displayName:string)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

Category dump: [image: Category dump]

Comment: I'm certain this works if there are `links` in `category` ;-). Can you reproduce in a Plunker? Do you get any error in the browser console?

Comment: No, I don't have any errors in my console

Comment: share your `categories` object structure when you `console.log` the `categories`.

Comment: Have you checked the DOM in the devtools if something is rendered within the `<ul>` element?

Comment: @ranakrunal9, Günter Zöchbauer see my updated post

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `displayName` in the categories (`{{link.displayName}}`) Try changing `{{link.displayName}}` to `{{link?.displayName}}`

Comment: You want to show displayName but in your model its called name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your `categories` object structure HTML should be as below :

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let category of categories">
  <h3>{{category.name}} ({{category.links.length}})</h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let link of category.links">
        <a [href]="link.url" target="_blank">{{link.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had an error in my code in my service. I am looping through the json data and I was adding the wrong object to the list. Hence the mistake between `name` and `displayName`